# What are the Maven coordinates for the JCache API jar?

Tags: java, hazelcast, jcache, jsr107

I have an executable JAR (*not* a web app being deployed to a standard container like Tomcat, etc.) that needs to connect to a DB and cache a lot of stuff.

If at all possible, I'd like to use the [JCache](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107) API and inject (via Guice) the Hazelcast implementation. I will code 100% against the JCache API, so that if I ever change my mind and choose another implementation, the swap out should be (relatively) painless.

**One problem: where can I get the latest stable JCache JAR?!?** (What are the Maven coordinates?)

On [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22jcache%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jcache%22), all I can find are some **dev** JARs from **2005**! So I ask: **where is the JCache?**

Comment: This question is not a dupe, shows research and is ABSOLUTELY on topic. Can someone please explain to me the reasons for both the downvote and closevote (btw, do you know when to use both of those properly)?

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 3):

The jar are available here : [javax.cache/cache-api](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.cache%7Ccache-api%7C1.0.0%7Cjar)

Comment: Thanks @Jeremie B (+1) - I was searching for "*jcache*" (go figure). How did you find this (just so I know for the future)?

Comment: just search for the package `javax.cache` in maven central : http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22javax.cache%22

Comment: Thanks again (+1) - but how did you know to search for "*javax.cache*" instead of by the APIs logical name "jcache"?

Comment: Any thoughts here, @Jeremie B?

Comment: all APIs are under the package `javax.cache`

Comment: Thanks @Jeremie B - but the point of my question was "*how did you know that?* How did you know that all JSR-107 APIs are packaged under `javax.cache`, because I was searching for JSR-107's canonical name `jcache`...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Ehcache implementations, copy/past the dependencies below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Find a complete example [here](http://www.opentuto.com/premier-programme-jcache/).